# javascript/jquery one object insert to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two objects and I need one object inserted into other in the first row.

I found Javascript function `splice`, but i don't know how use it.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var person = {};    
    person[0] = {};
    person[0]['name'] = 'Joy';
    person[0]['age'] = '12';

    var personAll = {}; 
    personAll[0] = {};
    personAll[0]['name'] = 'Vanda';
    personAll[0]['age'] = '49';
    personAll[1] = {};
    personAll[1]['name'] = 'Peter';
    personAll[1]['age'] = '12';

    var new_object = personAll.splice(0, person);

    //I need get this result:
    new_object[0]['name'] = 'Joy';
    new_object[0]['age'] = '12';
    new_object[1]['name'] = 'Vanda';
    new_object[1]['age'] = '49';
    new_object[2]['name'] = 'Peter';
    new_object[2]['age'] = '12';

    console.log(new_object);
});
```

How do I fix this code?

Comment: You should use (non-empty) object literals.

Comment: @Zeaklous No, they don't. The `var` lines declare objects, the subsequent lines declare properties of those objects, so they aren't creating any new variables at the function scope.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

`splice()` also takes the number of items to remove.
You need to call it like this:

```
array.splice(startIndex, howManyToRemove, newItems...);
```

In this case, you probably want to remove `0` items.

---

If you're inserting at the beginning of the array, you can also simply call `unshift()`.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are indexing a OBJ.  Splicing is done with arrays.   I would make an array of objects, and then splice accordingly.

See also:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you make person and personAll arrays, you can use the concat method.

```
var new_object = person.concat(personAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method remove elements from array.
You need to use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method, like this:

```
var person = {name: 'Joy', age: 12};
var persons = [{name: 'Vanda', age: 49}, {name: 'Peter', age: 12}];
var newPersons = [person].concat(persons);
console.log(newPersons);
```

Console output will be:  [image]